# How to "open" locked terminal when Django server is running on VSCode (What hotkey is being pressed here)?

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

I am trying to do this Django tutorial and came a cross problem where I cannot write to terminal when Django server is running. Here is excact spot on tutorial: https://youtu.be/uhSmgR1hEwg?list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kCLWnGmK0jUBmGLaJxvi4j&t=552

Tuotorial teacher clearly presses some hotkey to "enable" writing to terminal (that reveals `PC: C:\Users...` line). But what might that hotkey be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He just used `ctrl + c` to quit the running server.

this is working on both windows and linux operating system terminals.